# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 43; The reference to entity "l" must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, blogger

Getting This error while adding google tag manager code in html after <head> and in body blogerspot

I tried to implement google tag manager code in bloggerspot

Answer (score 0):

Hope you got the solution for this question. If not, please replace '&' with '&amp;' in the GTM embed script, which is sorting it out.

Thanks to Google Support [Link](https://support.google.com/blogger/thread/85913272/installing-google-analytics-error-message-org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-linenumber-8-columnnumb?hl=en) for sharing this solution

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue//need urgent resolution make sure you choice simple theme (Travel/*Road* Theme) and tried with one youtuber reference he suggest that remove l and add &

And all code working fine.

Hope this will help you too...

Answer (score -1):

replace all & with & and try again.
e.g. '&l' to '&'
[replace this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3epW.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).